# Google Auth web-view shutdown discrepancies

Tags: android, ios, webview, google-oauth

> "Notice to developers: The authentication request in the embedded browser will be blocked on April 20, 2017."

The above warning message was displayed while implementing google's OAuth on web-view on Android and iOS.  According to the message, it seems to be blocked from `April 20, 2017`.

However, it is not blocked yet.

I would like to confirm following questions.

- Why is Android not displaying the warning message? (only iOS will be blocked?)
- The expected date(April 20) has already passed, but when will it be blocked? (I'd like to know the exact dates when it will be blocked.)
- Can I get notice before being block?
- Is the blocking target only a request from webview? (whether it is affected the entire account)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is Android not displaying the warning message? (only iOS will be blocked?)

Probably because your code isnt using a webview and is using device browser for OAuth.  But TBH i don't think i have seen the error displayed on Android.  Yes both android and IOS will be blocked.

> The expected date(April 20) has already passed, but when will it be blocked? (I'd like to know the exact dates when it will be blocked.)

Google is huge there is no master button that says kill it all now.  Their dates are more a warning when things are going to start being shut down.  It can take a few months for everything to be blocked.  I would fix your code now.

> Can I get notice before being block?

On August 22 2016, google notified all developers via a blog post [Modernizing OAuth interactions in Native Apps for Better Usability and Security](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) you have already been notified.

> Is the blocking target only a request from webview? (whether it is affected the entire account)

Its only code using a web-view for authentication.

Comment: I didn't get any warning about this change and have just found out by incident that my app doesn't login with google. Bad behaviour of Google. Also they could give us information how to change the asp.net mvc template to work after this block.

Comment: "August 22 2016, google notified all developers via a blog post Modernizing OAuth interactions in Native Apps for Better Usability and Security" as a developer it's your responsibility to keep yourself updated and read the blog posts.

Comment: No. It's there responsibility when changing something that affects their clients to notify them and provide them with the solution. I didn't even know this blog exists, and I don't have to check it many times to zee if something has changed. Facebook does just that and I would have done the same to my clients.

Comment: The solution is to not use a web view for authentication and to use the OS browser instead. That is in the blog post I believe.

Comment: So I will have to redirect the user to open a browser and complete the login there and then return back to the webview? I think I will just remove the google login from the mobile web site.

Comment: It happened also to Xiaomi Mi app. I wonder How many apps got broken because of that.